# Minio removeObject

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I'm trying to programmatically remove something from my S3 bucket, and I'm using Minio to facilitate it.

When I run minioClient.removeObject() like so:

```
minioClient.removeObject(RemoveObjectArgs.builder().bucket(minioBucketName).object(key).build());
```

the function returns void. So I'm unsure how to validate that my object was deleted without sending an additional request off to see if it exists (i feel like this is one step too many).

If the deletion is successful, the object is gone. If the deletion is unsuccessful (maybe provided the wrong key) I'm not really told it was unsuccessful. It just attempts to do it and that's the last I hear about the operation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The removeObjects return `Iterable<Result<DeleteError>> - Lazy iterator contains object removal status.` You can refer this code and check for error if present .

```
List<DeleteObject> objects = new LinkedList<>();
objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname1"));
objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname2"));
objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname3"));
Iterable<Result<DeleteError>> results =
    minioClient.removeObjects(
        RemoveObjectsArgs.builder().bucket("my-bucketname").objects(objects).build());
for (Result<DeleteError> result : results) {
  DeleteError error = result.get();
  System.out.println(
      "Error in deleting object " + error.objectName() + "; " + error.message());
}
```